# How to calculate the "boundingBox" of a glTF object

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, bounding-box, gltf

I know that the concept of "boundingBox" is not present in the glTF specifications, but what is the appropriate way to **calculate the boundaries** of a glTF object in a manner that can be compared to other assets, in a "grosso modo" way, to determine which object is wider or higher proportionally to its size? So if object A looks 3x bigger than object B in a glTF viewer or engine, that measure should reflect that. Making an assumption that there is only one node.

I'm using **SharpGLTF**, but the answer could be regarding glTF specifications in general.

While the scale can provide some insight into the relative sizes of objects, it does not directly indicate the size comparison between them.

Answer (score 0):

A common choice here would be an [axis-aligned bounding box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection#axis-aligned_bounding_boxes) (AABB). The glTF spec requires accessors containing vertex attribute position data to [include min/max bounds](https://registry.khronos.org/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html#accessors-bounds), which represent a local AABB for each mesh primitive in the file. Alternatively you could iterate over the vertex data to compute the min/max. Pseudocode:

```py
for mesh in json.meshes:
  for prim in mesh.primitives:
    position = json.accessors[prim['POSITION']]
    min = position.min # vec3
    max = position.max # vec3
```

After obtaining a local AABB for each mesh primitive, you'd then need to convert that to a world space AABB. Usually that means computing the world matrix of the node where the mesh is attached, then applying the inverse of that matrix to the AABB. If the scene contains multiple nodes, take the union of the AABBs.

Optionally, you might look at skinning, morph target, and keyframe animation data to compute bounds during animation, but for the use case described that is probably not necessary.